# Is it possible to find who are the top 100 users in some tag?

Tags: support, statistics, top-users

When pressing the 'top users' in a  tag you can view the top 20 people in each category of score - answerers and askers last 30 days and all time.

Can you get more info in this topic? For example, who are the top 100 answerers in the last year or how many total points do they have?

Comment: you can check https://data.stackexchange.com.. for example top users in a tag query http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/534372/top-tag-users-score-0

Comment: @suraj: that query doesn't actually name the users, only their tag score and rank.

Comment: @codygray is there a specific reason you left the feature-request tag and didn't replace it with the support tag for instance? I'm hesitant to change it as you made an explicit tag edit.

Comment: @rene No, no specific reason. I saw the [feature-request] tag first, and that colored my interpretation of the question. I assumed a feature was actually being requested, rather than that he was just looking for a Data Explorer query. Not sure, though. Re-reading the question, it does not appear to be especially feature-request-y. Feel free to tweak the tags. :-)

Comment: Better query, based on the answer on the duplicate: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/708168/top-n-answerers-for-a-given-tag